# JSON.NET Deserialize Object or Array POCO

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using NewtonSoft.JSON to parse my data. My goal is to create an object called SalesLines that contains a List:

```
public class SalesLines
{
   public List<SalesLine> SalesLines {get; set;}
}
```

My data is sometimes an array and sometimes an object:

```
 "SaleLines": {
"SaleLine": [
      {
        "saleLineID": "3963",

        },
        }]}



"SaleLines": {
    "SaleLine": { "salesLineID": "3333" };
```

How do I create a POCO in this scenario? My current solutions works, but it is messy:

```
string salesLineJson = sale.SaleLines.SaleLine.ToString();

var salesLineToken = JToken.Parse(salesLineJson);

if (salesLineToken is JArray)
{                     
   sale.SaleLines.Lines.AddRange(JArray.Parse(salesLineJson).ToObject<List<SaleLine>>());
}
else if (salesLineToken is JObject)
{
   sale.SaleLines.Lines.Add(JObject.Parse(salesLineJson).ToObject<SaleLine>());
}
```

Comment: Is there an option to "fix" the source of your data so it's _always_ an array, so it matches your target object type all the time?

Comment: Sorry, there is no option. The data is messed up, I believe.

Comment: In that case, then yes you're probably stuck with code like the above.  You could probably refactor it into a subclass of `JsonConverter` that you can pass an instance of to `Deserialize` so it's in a useful helper class for reuse elsewhere, but at some point you're going to have to manually check the token as you've done already